Altering Substitution Strings in Oracle Apex by SQL script
I have an APEX application which has a customized substitution stirng, the value would be different for different environments(dev/test/prod). I am using the visual builder studio build job to deploy the application, however, after each deployment, the substitution string is changed back to the value from dev environment due to the install scrips are exported from dev env.
Is there any way to update the substitution string by sql script? So I can integrate it into the build job. Update the value each time after the deployment. Thanks

I found a workaround. Create a shell script in the Visual Builder Studio build job before running the APEX app install script. In the shell script, replace the substitution string with the sed command. As I exported the app into separated SQL files, it was pretty straightforward to update the substitution string in one file. And it worked as expected.
